# Conectar a DB MySQL con PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en PHP y estoy siguiendo el siguiente curso.
https://programadorwebvalencia.com/cursos/php/

He creado los siguientes archivos y una base de datos, llamada portal, con el usuario usuario_portal en phpMyAdmin. Me gustaría, saber como conectarlo todo con el conector de MySQL PDO, ya que en el ejemplo, lo hace, con el conector SQLite. ¿Qué debería de cambiar para ello? Gracias.

Aquí los archivos:

login.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            // Comprobamos que nos llega los datos del formulario
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                // Base de datos ficticia que se usará en el ejemplo.
                $baseDeDatos = [
                    'email' => 'correo@falso.com',
                    'password' => password_hash('123', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
                ];
                
                // Variables del formulario
                $emailFormulario = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : null;
                $contrasenyaFormulario = isset($_REQUEST['contrasenya']) ? $_REQUEST['contrasenya'] : null;

                // Comprobamos si los datos son correctos
                if ($baseDeDatos['email'] == $emailFormulario && password_verify($contrasenyaFormulario, $baseDeDatos['password'])) {
                    // Si son correctos, creamos la sesión
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
                    // Redireccionamos a la página segura
                    header('Location: privado.php');
                    die();
                } else {
                    // Si no son correctos, informamos al usuario
                    echo '<p style="color: red">El e-mail o la contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta.</p>';
                }
            }
        ?>
        <h2>Registro de Miembros</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="e-mail" placeholder="E-mail"> 
            </p> 
            <p>
                <input type="password" name="contrasenya" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a"> 
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Entrar"> 
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

privado.php

```
<?php
// Activa las sesiones
session_start();
// Comprueba si existe la sesión 'email', en caso contrario vuelve a la página de login
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) header('Location: login.php');
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            ¡Te encuentras en una zona secreta!, solo visible por una persona identificada.
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="cerrar-sesion.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
sesssion_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location:login.php");
?>
```

registro.php

```
<?php
//======================================================================
// PROCESAR FORMULARIO 
//======================================================================

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Funciones Para Validar
//-----------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Método que valida si un texto no esta vacío
 * @param {string} - Texto a validar
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function validar_requerido(string $texto): bool
{
    return !(trim($texto) == '');
}

/**
 * Método que valida si el texto tiene un formato válido de E-Mail
 * @param {string} - Email
 * @return {bool}
 */
function validar_email(string $texto): bool
{
    return filter_var($texto, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Variables
//-----------------------------------------------------
$errores = [];
$email = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : '';
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? $_REQUEST['password'] : '';

// Comprobamos si nos llega los datos por POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Validaciones
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Email
    if (!validar_requerido($email)) {
        $errores[] = 'Campo Email obligatorio.';
    }

    if (!validar_email($email)) {
        $errores[] = 'Campo Email no tiene un formato válido';
    }

    // Contraseña
    if (!validar_requerido($password)) {
        $errores[] = 'Campo Contraseña obligatorio.';
    }

    /* Verificar que no existe en la base de datos el mismo email */
    // Conecta con base de datos
    $miPDO = new PDO('sqlite:base-de-datos.sqlite');
    // Cuenta cuantos emails existen
    $miConsulta = $miPDO->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as length FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email;');
    // Ejecuta la busqueda
    $miConsulta->execute([
        'email' => $email
    ]);
    // Recoge los resultados
    $resultado = $miConsulta->fetch();
    // Comprueba si existe
    if ((int) $resultado['length'] > 0) {
        $errores[] = 'La dirección de email ya esta registrada.';
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Crear cuenta
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    if (count($errores) === 0) {
        /* Registro En La Base De Datos */

        // Prepara INSERT
        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
        $miNuevoRegistro = $miPDO->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (email, password, activo, token) VALUES (:email, :password, :activo, :token);');
        // Ejecuta el nuevo registro en la base de datos
        $miNuevoRegistro->execute([
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
            'activo' => 0,
            'token' => $token
        ]);

        /* Envío De Email Con Token */

        // Cabecera
        $headers = [
            'From' => 'curso@php.com',
            'Content-type' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
        ];
        // Variables para el email
        $emailEncode = urlencode($email);
        $tokenEncode = urlencode($token);
        // Texto del email
        $textoEmail = "
           Hola!\n 
           Gracias por registrate en la mejor plataforma de internet, demuestras inteligencia.\n
           Para activar entra en el siguiente enlace:\n
           http://midomino.com/verificar-cuenta.php?email=$emailEncode&token=$tokenEncode
            ";
        // Envio del email
        mail($email, 'Activa tu cuenta', 'Gracias por suscribirte', $headers);

        /* Redirección a login.php con GET para informar del envio del email */

        header('Location: identificarse.php?registrado=1');
        die();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registro</h1>
    <!-- Mostramos errores por HTML -->
    <?php if (isset($errores)): ?>
    <ul class="errores">
        <?php 
            foreach ($errores as $error) {
                echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
            } 
        ?> 
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- Formulario -->
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <!-- Campo de Email -->
            <label>
                E-mail
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- Campo de Contraseña -->
            <label>
                Contraseña
                <input type="text" name="password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- Botón submit -->
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

verificar-cuenta.php

```
<?php

//-----------------------------------------------------
// Variables
//-----------------------------------------------------
$email = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['email']) : '';
$token = isset($_REQUEST['token']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['token']) : '';

//-----------------------------------------------------
// COMPROBAR SI SON CORRECTOS LOS DATOS
//-----------------------------------------------------
// Conecta con base de datos
$miPDO = new PDO('sqlite:base-de-datos.sqlite');
// Prepara SELECT para obtener la contraseña almacenada del usuario
$miConsulta = $miPDO->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as length FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND token = :token AND activo = 0;');
// Ejecuta consulta
$miConsulta->execute([
    'email' => $email,
    'token' => $token
]);
$resultado = $miConsulta->fetch();
// Existe el usuario con el token
if ((bool) $resultado['length']) {
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // ACTIVAR CUENTA
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Prepara la actualización
    $miActualiacion = $miPDO->prepare('UPDATE usuarios SET activo = 1 WHERE email = :email;');
    // Ejecuta actualización
    $miActualiacion->execute([
        'email' => $email
    ]);
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // REDIRECCIONAR A IDENTIFICACION
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    header('Location: identificarse.php?activada=1');
    die();
}

// No es un usuario válido, le enviamos al formulario de identificación
header('Location: identificarse.php');
die();
```

identificarse.php

```
<?php 
    //======================================================================
    // PROCESAR FORMULARIO 
    //======================================================================
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Variables
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    $email = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : null;
    $password = isset($_REQUEST['contrasenya']) ? $_REQUEST['contrasenya'] : null;
    $errores = [];

    // Comprobamos que nos llega los datos del formulario
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        //-----------------------------------------------------
        // COMPROBAR SI LA CUENTA ESTA ACTIVA
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        // Conecta con base de datos
        $miPDO = new PDO('sqlite:base-de-datos.sqlite');
        // Prepara SELECT para obtener la contraseña almacenada del usuario
        $miConsulta = $miPDO->prepare('SELECT activo, password FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email;');
        // Ejecuta consulta
        $miConsulta->execute([
            'email' => $email
        ]);
        // Guardo el resultado
        $resultado = $miConsulta->fetch();
        if ((int) $resultado['activo'] !== 1) {
            $errores[] = 'Tu cuenta aún no esta activa. ¿Has comprobado tu bandeja de correo?';
        } else {
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            // COMPROBAR LA CONTRASEÑA
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            // Comprobamos si es válida
            if (password_verify($password, $resultado['password'])) {
                // Si son correctos, creamos la sesión
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                // Redireccionamos a la página segura
                header('Location: privado.php');
                die();
            } else {
                $errores[] = 'El email o la contraseña es incorrecta.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Entra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Entrar</h1>
    <!-- Mostramos errores por HTML -->
    <?php if (count($errores) > 0): ?>
    <ul class="errores">
        <?php 
            foreach ($errores as $error) {
                echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
            } 
        ?> 
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- Mensaje de aviso al registrarte -->
    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['registrado'])): ?> 
    <p>¡Gracias por registrarte! Revista tu bandeja de correo para activar la cuenta.</p>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <!-- Mensaje de cuenta activa -->
    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['activada'])): ?> 
    <p>¡Cuenta activada!</p>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <!-- Formulario de identificación -->
    <form method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"> 
        </p> 
        <p>
            <input type="password" name="contrasenya" placeholder="Contraseña"> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar"> 
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

dbconnect.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "portal";
$username = "usuario_portal";
$password = "";
$charset = "utf8mb4_general_ci";

try {

$dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;charset=$charset";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

echo “Connection Okay”;

return $pdo

}

catch (PDOException $e)

{
echo “Connection failed: ”. $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a SOes. Por favor lee el [tour]. Te sugiero leer **[The only proper PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)**

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. para MySQL con PDO es básicamente lo mismo, solo cambia a `new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'username', 'password')`, aquí cambiaran los parámetros según la configuración de tu **DB**, Te sugiero una leída al articulo [PHP PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php), recuerda tambien tener instalado el driver de PDO.

Comment: [Aquí el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) te explica cómo debes construir el DSN para conectarte a una base de datos MySQL usando PDO. Revisa los ejemplos 1 y 2. Por ejemplo, si MySQL no está en el puerto por defecto, debes indicar el puerto de forma explícita, como muestra el ejemplo 2. Inténtalo y si no funciona dinos qué error ocurre. Lo de `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',` es para versiones viejas de PHP, actualmente puedes pasar el charset en el DSN, como muestran algunos ejemplos en las Notas de Contribución, al pie del enlace.